# Docker container port mapping doesn't work after few try

Tags: docker

I'm using Windows11 and docker with WSL2.
There are some strange erros blocks me from testing.

When map the port and using it, port became unreachable after few buld and run.
When it happens, I change server's listening port to other and map the port with that number, it works again in different port.

Dockerfile is

```
# Docker script for nestjs server -- For testing
FROM node:18

RUN mkdir -p /app
WORKDIR /app

COPY ./ ./

RUN npm ci

ENTRYPOINT ["npm", "run", "start:dev"]
EXPOSE 8000
```

And Node server are listening on 0.0.0.0:8080 inside container.

At the first, build via `docker build .` and run via `docker run <image> -p 8080:8080` workings.
But after reboot or few repeated trial of `docker build` and `docker run` port become unavailable (Connection refused)

When working, `docker inspect` show below result

```json
"NetworkSettings": {
        // Other fields...
        "Ports": {
            "8000/tcp": [
                {
                    "HostIp": "",
                    "HostPort": "8000"
                }
            ]
        },
        // Other fields...
}
```

But suddenly when I deploy another build and run with same config (No dockerfile changes, no code changes)
It become like below and port are not available (Connection refused)

```json
"NetworkSettings": {
        // Other fields...
        "Ports": {
            "8000/tcp": null
        },
        // Other fields...
}
```

I'm quite new to docker, i wonder why this is happening.